# Does AWS CloudFront stop working after I breach FreeTier limits

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I am using AWS CloudFront and I'm currently free-tier.

I am close to going over 2.000.000 HTTP/S requests that is max allowed for free-tier.

Will AWS automatically charge me for the traffic that goes over those 2.000.000 requests (per on-demand prices) or will CloudFront become unavailable and stop receiving more requests? How do I upgrade to on-demand?

Comment: AWS will never not bill you when they can ;) that is a common criticism that you cannot just use the free tier but always run the risk of being billed something if you do not turn things off fast enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloudfront will still be available, however, you will be charged requests for over the max allowed free tiers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes AWS will automatically charge for any excess usage over the free tier quota. Any resource you created in your account will not affect and they will work without any interruption. You do not need to do any upgrades from your side to cater to increased requests.

If you are budget concerned, you can create AWS Budget and create an alert so AWS will notify you before you reach a pre-defined budget. From there you can also define what to do if you reach the budget. For example, you can shut down ec2 instances if this resource consumed more than the allocated budget.